# Symfony Argument error wgen i'm added event subscriber

Tags: php, symfony

I have a constructor for controller which gelp me handle

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

   private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
       $this->repository =  $em->getRepository(Interview::class);
    }
```

And all work fine until i add event subscribers in services.yml:

```
services:
  AppBundle\EventListener\InterviewListener:
        tags:
            - { name: event_subscriber}
```

after this my app generate error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Controller\InterviewController::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, none given, called in
>   /home/deymaz/Dev/interview/interview/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
>   on line 195

Answer (score 0):

Your InterviewListener service config (in services.yml) will either need autoconfiguration setup, or to add the relevant argument.

If you are running Symfony 3.3+, with [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html) enabled, and the class `implements EventSubscriberInterface` then the rest of the config may not be needed, as it would already be configured automatically.